time complexity of this problem "Asymptotic Running Time Discrepancy: O(nlogn) vs O(n) Using Master Theorem
Consider the following procedure, which takes as input an array A. What is the
asymptotic running time of printStuff subroutine?

here I have done normal method step by step calculation, I got O(nlogn) but while using the master method I'm getting O(n) so what is the correct answer
Here the work i have done
The length of the array 'A' is 'n'.
If 'n' is equal to 4 or less than 4, then the function returns immediately. Therefore, this operation takes constant time, so the time complexity is O(1).
If 'n > 4', the algorithm prints all elements of the array 'A'.
Since the loop iterates over all 'n' elements, this operation takes O(n).
From Recursive Calls:
There are two recursive calls in the function:
One on the first quarter of the array: printstuff(A[n/4:])
The other on the last quarter of the array: printstuff(A[3n/4:])
Recurrence Relation:
The work done by the function to print all the elements of the array is O(n).
There are two recursive calls: one on a subarray of size n/4 and another on a subarray of size 3n/4.
From this recurrence relation:
T(n) = T(n/4) + T(3n/4) + O(n)
Solving the Recurrence Relation:
Initial Work at Level 0:
T(n) = O(n)
Work at Level 1:
The work done by the two recursive calls is:
T(n/4) + T(3n/4)
Thus, the total work at level 1 is:
T(n/4) + T(3n/4) + O(n)
The total work at Level 1 = O(n).
Work at Level 2:
At this level, the recursive calls from T(n/4) and T(3n/4) split into smaller parts:
T(n/16) + T(3n/16) + T(3n/16) + T(9n/16) + O(n)
So, the total work done at this level adds up to O(n).
The total work at Level 2 = O(n).
This process continues until 'n' is less than or equal to 4.
Recursion Tree:
The depth of the recursion tree is determined by how many times we can divide the problem size before it becomes n ≤ 4. Since we are reducing the problem size by factors of 1/4 and 3/4 at each step, the depth of the recursion tree is O(log n).
Thus, the total work is:
O(n) × O(log n) = O(n log n)
Conclusion:
The overall time complexity of the algorithm is O(n log n).

I’m voting to close this question because this might be better asked on https://math.stackexchange.com/

Please show your work on how you got these two results.

i have edited my question by adding work i done

It's O( n )
here is why:
Let's simplify the function a little bit:

this will take the same time it's just that the array will be printed in another order
Anyway let's compute the complexity:
firstly it will print from 0 to n,
then it will print from 0 to n/2
then from 0 to n/2/2 (n/4), and so on.
so it will be:
n + n/2 + n/4 + n/8 + n/16...
1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + 1/16... is mathematically proven to be = 1
so the complexity will be n + n -> 2n -> n
so it's:
O(n)
Here is a program in c++ that tests the algorithm and the comparison between both cases (two 1/4 calls or one 1/2 call) and you can play around with it as you want for sure:
#include <iostream>;
using namespace std;
int time2 = 0;
int time4 = 0;

int printStuffBy2(long double* a, long long len) {
    if (len <= 4) {
        return 0;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        //cout << a[i] << endl;
        time2++;
    }
    //cout << endl;
    long double* tempA = new long double[len / 2];
    for (long long i = 0; i < len / 2; i++) {
        tempA[i] = a[i];
    }
    
    printStuffBy2(tempA, len / 2);
    return 0;
}

int printStuffBy4(long double* a, long long len) {
    if (len <= 4) {
        return 0;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        //cout << a[i] << endl;
        time4++;
    }
    //cout << endl;
    long double* tempA = new long double[len / 4];
    for (long long i = 0; i < len / 4; i++) {
        tempA[i] = a[i];
    }

    long double* tempA2 = new long double[len / 4];
    long long j = 0;
    for (long long i = (3 * len / 4); i < len; i++) {
        tempA2[j] = a[i];
        j++;
    }

    printStuffBy4(tempA, len / 4);
    printStuffBy4(tempA2, len / 4);
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    long double len = 10000000;
    long double* a = new long double[len];
    for (long long i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        a[i] = i;
    }
    printStuffBy2(a, len);
    printStuffBy4(a, len);

    cout << endl << time2 << endl << time4;

    return 0;
}


You cannot just change the two recursive calls passing a quarter by one that passes half. This influences the depth at which the base case kicks in. For instance, if you start with an array that has 64 elements, the original algorithm will first print 64 values, and at the next recursion level it will print twice 16 values. At deeper levels nothing is printed. Your variant will print 64 values, then 32 values, then 16 values, then 8 values. This is not the same.

It's not about the output it's about the time, believe me, it's the same time, I even made a program and tested it on 100, 1000, 1 000 000, and 1 000 000 000, and they all gave the same time in both cases.

You have to provide more than just "believe me". There is no proof of that in your answer.
